# Html inside php, including javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to do following things:

in my index.php I have:

```
$GLOBALS['MAINURL'] = "http://localhost/myapp/";
```

in the function in which I am generating the page header:

```
public function header() {
     echo"<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang='en'>
     <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

        <!-- Bootstrap themes stuff here -->

        <title>My app title</title>    

        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='" . $GLOBALS['MAINURL'] . "Common/main.js'></script>
      </head>
      <body role='document'>";
}
```

And footer:

```
public function footer() {
     echo "                
        <footer class='footer'>
            <div class='container'>
                <p class='text-muted'>abc</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='". $GLOBALS['MAINURL'] . "Common/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script src='". $GLOBALS['MAINURL'] . "Common/js/docs.min.js'> ";   
}
```

The problem is in concatenating "MAINURL" with the rest of the path for bootstrap.min.js, docs.min.js and main.js (even though they are correct - I echoed them). When starting the app I have following error in the browser's console:

*main.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*

*bootstrap.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*

*docs.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*

It doesn't have a problem when I set

```
$GLOBALS['MAINURL'] = "http://localhost/";
```

- without "myapp/". But then the resources are not found. Do you have any idea how to deal with it? I would rather stay with the directory structure and *myapp* folder.

Comment: Could you show us the output of the page?

Comment: you have missed `"` in your question code. in both `header()` and  `footer()`

Comment: @Thomas, the page is almost blank - no styles loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It turned out my .htaccess file was breaking everything. Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

close your echo here:

```
<body role='document'> " // << Needs closure
}
```

Alsl check your js files. It appears that they're being openeed but they're just not correctly written, becase jquery.min which you get from google is giving you no problems.

Comment: I think my .js's are correctly written, IDE doesn't complain about them. Especially when bootstrap.min.js and docs.min.js are default ones.

For some unknown reason the problem is with the URL concatenation.

Comment: try to echo only this: src='" . $GLOBALS['MAINURL'] . "Common/main.js'

Comment: the result is: 'http://localhost/myapp/Common/main.js'. Which seems correct